# Omit each vertex in turn of convex polygon: Iterative limit?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, discrete-geometry

Let $P=P_0$ be a convex polygon of $n$ vertices $v_k$.
Let $P_{i+1}$ be the convex polygon obtained by intersecting the halfplanes
determined by the lines through every other vertex.
Below, $P_0$ is an octagon. $P_1$ is the green-shaded octagon
bound by (red) lines through $v_1 v_3$, $v_2 v_4$, $v_3 v_5$, etc.
$P_2$ is the tan-shaded octagon bound by green lines.

---

[image: OctagonInscribed]

---

> For generic $P_0$,
>   does $P_k$ for $k \to \infty$ approach some identifiable limit shape, when rescaled?

I feel certain this process has been studied but I am not remembering where
I may have seen it, or what search terms would lead me to it.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the [pentagram map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagram_map), about which much is known.  Not by me, or I would give a nicer summary.  But the Wikipedia article has plenty of references.  In a quick scan of it I don't see a direct answer to your specific question about the limit after rescaling.  It seems that usually the polygons are considered up to projective equivalence, and then the pentagram map is integrable.